# jQuery animate not working with bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5.

I have this `a` element:

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTicket" id="scrollDown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTicket">
        نوشتن پاسخ
    </a>
</div>
<div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
    Test 1
</div>
<br/>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseTicket" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
    Test 2
</div>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Then I have some other elements, like other text inputs, textareas, etc.

When the user clicks on that input with #collapseTicket, the page should scroll to the last element of the page with a nice animation. It should be a scroll to a tag and not to the top.

The animation should not be too fast and should be fluid.

I am running the latest jQuery version. I prefer to not install any plugin but to use the default jQuery features to achieve this.

```
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery-3.5.1.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/defaults-fa_IR.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/vue/vue.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/vue/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/vue/moment-jalaali.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/vue/vue-persian-datetime-picker-browser.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/script.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            date: ''
        },
        components: {
            DatePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
        }
    });
</script>
@include('sweet::alert')
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#scrollDown").click(function (){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollDown: $("#collapseTicket").offset().down
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Thanks for answer.

Comment: `offset()` doesn't have a `down` property. There is only `top` and `left`. https://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Change `down` to `top`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rory pointed out, jQuery doesn’t have a `down` property, so you should be using `top` as in: `$("#collapseTicket").offset().top`

A second problem is jQuery’s animate doesn’t have a `scrollDown` property, just `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` so you can scroll to the top or the left edge of an element.

One other complication for animating the scroll to a position is that Bootstrap 5 sets `scroll-behavior` on the root element to `smooth`. That causes at least Chrome to move slowly at first as jQuery is sending a series of scroll commands, each of which moves the display a little bit. That’s why, in the snippet below, I set the `:root` to `scroll-behavior: auto;`

```js
$(function() {
    $("#scrollDown").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#collapseTicket").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    :root {
        scroll-behavior: auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="mb-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTicket" id="scrollDown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTicket">
        نوشتن پاسخ
    </a>
</div>
<div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width: 100px;">
    Test 1
</div>
<br />
<div class="collapse" id="collapseTicket" style="width: 100px;">
    Test 2
</div>
<div style="height: 1000px; width: 100px; background-color: salmon;">
    filler
</div>
```

If you want, you could use `window.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)");` to manage your scroll behavior.

According to [Can I User](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior), Safari does not currently support `scroll-behavior`.